# HAProxy - how to setup timeout for connection with no request?

Tags: haproxy, timeout

I have a public facing server that uses HA Proxy as front end. I use TCP mode. I want to set it up such that if the client established connection (completed 3-way handshake) but does not send any payload within certain amount of time, the connection will timeout quickly. But if the client has sent at least some payload, connection will timeout normally.

I looked at the various timeout options offered by HAProxy but I cannot seem to find one that matches my need?

Comment: There should be a way to accomplish this by using a bit of roundabout logic involving tcp content inspection, using that to "trick" the proxy into stalling request processing for a few seconds under the guise of being interested in the actual payload bytes prior to establishing the back-end connection... but then immediately cancelling the wait once some payload arrives.  What protocol is being spoken over the TCP connection?

Comment: It is some service over SSL. It sounded like you are suggesting the server do something to close the connection. I don't have control over the servers. Instead, I want to use HAProxy to handle those situations.